# Can't create a GWT web application in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gwt

I'm installing the plugin following these istruction http://gwt-plugins.github.io/documentation/gwt-eclipse-plugin/Download.html
The installation appears to be successful (if i go on the installed plugins I can see GWT Eclipse plugin 3.0.0) , but when I have to create a new web application I don't find the button for create it. I tried to search the button in "other" too.
Eclipse version: 4.22.0

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I might be facing the same issue.

Comment: I haven't found any solution for the plugin. I will try using the archetype after exams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The eclipse plugin is not fully maintained right now, the recommended way for creating new GWT projects is to use a multi module archetype that separate the client from the server, there is already a good archetype to do that you can find it here [tbroyer gwt archetype](https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes) and follow the instructions in the readme file to check how you can run the application.

Comment: Oh nice. I didn't know it was no longer maintained. I will try to follow these instructions. Thank u.

Comment: Nevertheless the Eclipse GWT Plugin still works with Eclipre 2021-12/4.22.0. I didn't test installing the plugin under this version. I had an older Eclipse with the plugin, and then I updated it. - If you don't find the button, try file -> new -> Project... and then choose "GWT application"

Comment: I don't have the option "GWT application" (not even in "other")